# What are these c++ statements doing

Tags: c++

```
void useproxynum    ( ) { bUseProxy = true; return; };
void useacctnum     ( ) { bUseProxy = false; return; };
```

Can anyone give me some insight into what these c++ statements are doing? There are in a header file. 
bUseProxy is defined above

```
bool    bUseProxy;
```

I'm trying to figure out what useproxynum is (method call?) and I'm also trying to figure out how to find the code behind it.

This is in Visual Studio 6.

Comment: There is no code behind it. That's all there is. And yes, its a method call.

Comment: There's no code behind it - only code in front of it! :-)

Comment: My understanding is that a method is a function that's a member of a class.  Since there's no context given (except that the definitions are in a header file), it's possible that these are not methods.  They certainly are functions.

Comment: "method" is not a C++ term and it's rather problematic using it.  Is '==' a "method"?  What if it isn't a member function?  It's clearly part of the interface, but is it a 'method'?  Many C++ programmers chose not to use the term because it simply has no clear meaning in C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are inline method definitions. The `return` statements are **extremely** unnecessary.

If it were me, i'd replace that with this:

```
void useNum(bool proxy) { bUseProxy = proxy; }
```

Comment: How is it **extremely** unnecessary vs. just ordinarily unnecessary?  ;)  (It's completely a no-op statement, so it's not like it really is extreme...)

Comment: @Reed: It's like infinite and 2x infinite, both are infinite, but one grows faster than the other :)

Comment: @Brian: It's more like it's **extremely** infinite.  That's way more than infinite, of course.  ;)

Comment: I guess on second thought it's more like saying 5 * 0 vs 0*0.  Clearly 0*0 is a more **extreme** 0 than 5*0!

Comment: Some statements are more unnecessary than others.

Comment: Are they more or less unnecessary than the semicolons after the function bodies?

Answer (score 4):

Those are not statements. Those are 2 methods (seems to be inline). One of them just sets true to **bUseProxy** variable the other sets false. Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

They are both methods.  The lines between the { } are the code.  These are inlined methods and don't have a separate implementation in a .cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `useproxynum()` in your code, and it will cause the `bUseProxy` value to be set to true.

Or, you can call `useacctnum()` in your code and it will cause `bUseProxy` to be false.

This `bUseProxy` is probably used somewhere else.

```
void doSomething(int id) {
    if(bUseProxy) {
        lookupWithProxy(id);
    }
    else {
        lookupWithAccNum(id);
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that the `return;` statements are kind of silly - reaching the end of the function block will cause the function to return all by itself.

"Trying to figure out the code behind it" ... no no, the code is in front of it =)

Comment: Does it show that c++ is not my strong suit. Don't tell my boss LOL.

Answer (score 1):

they are inline methods.
when called, they set the value of the boolean, then return.